# How do I use --remote in place of --app for Heroku CLI commands?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've generally used the --app flag for multiple apps, but recently found --remote.  I'd prefer the more generic --remote  but have been unable to get it to work.

"git remote" lists origin, staging, and production, yet running, for instance, "heroku logs --remote staging" yields a "No app specified" error.

I was told in the Heroku irc channel that this should work and that --remote can be used in place of --app.  What am I missing?

heroku-toolbelt v. 2.37.2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely an issue with your git remotes not being set up correctly to match the [regex in Toolbelt](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/70551392e6cb4a1bbe693d478407e9794081b28b/lib/heroku/command/base.rb#L208). To see the details of your remotes, run:

```
git remote -v
```

This should give you something like this:

```
dev     git@heroku.com:example-dev-ryan.git (push)
dev     git@heroku.com:example-dev-ryan.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ryanbrainard/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ryanbrainard/example.git (push)
prod    git@heroku.com:example.git (push)
prod    git@heroku.com:example.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:example-staging.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:example-staging.git (push)
```

Make sure that your Heroku git remotes match the [pattern](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/70551392e6cb4a1bbe693d478407e9794081b28b/lib/heroku/command/base.rb#L208):

```
^git@#{Heroku::Auth.git_host}(?:[\.\w]*):([\w\d-]+)\.git$
```

Where `#{Heroku::Auth.git_host}` is equal to `heroku.com`, unless you have overridden it in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Then you'll be able to use `--remote` (or `-r` for short), like this:

```
heroku info --remote prod
```

Comment: That's the issue.  I changed the host name to match my work ssh key in ~/.ssh/config so Heroku::Auth.git_host wasn't matching in the regex.

Comment: Great to hear. I just updated my answer to call out ~/.ssh/config overrides.